# confluent_kafka hangs on publish

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

When I try to run the hello world ([published here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python)) for `confluent-kafka==1.0.1` my process hangs on `p.flush()`. The debug message includes the following error:

```
 mytopic [0] 1 message(s) queued but broker not up
```

This is extremely confusing to me, because the application is clearly communicating with the broker. Before attempting to publish, it successfully creates the topic, which it couldn't do without interacting with the broker. I included the script, the environment it is running in, and the full log below.

I've no idea what could be going wrong here, so any advice would be appreciated.

Test script:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer

p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': f"{flask_application.config['KAFKA_HOST']}:9092",
              "debug": "topic,msg,broker"})


def delivery_report(err, msg):
    """ Called once for each message produced to indicate delivery result.
        Triggered by poll() or flush(). """
    if err is not None:
        print('Message delivery failed: {}'.format(err))
    else:
        print('Message delivered to {} [{}]'.format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))


for data in ['imadata']:
    # Trigger any available delivery report callbacks from previous produce() calls
    p.poll(0)

    # Asynchronously produce a message, the delivery report callback
    # will be triggered from poll() above, or flush() below, when the message has
    # been successfully delivered or failed permanently.
    p.produce('mytopic', data.encode('utf-8'), callback=delivery_report)
    print('produce called')

# Wait for any outstanding messages to be delivered and delivery report
# callbacks to be triggered.
print('calling flush')
p.flush()
print('flush called')
```

docker compose for kafka/zookeeper:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3.5.5-r11'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:2.2.1-r14'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

error log:

```
%7|1562193919.214|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Enter main broker thread
%7|1562193919.214|BROKER|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Added new broker with NodeId -1
%7|1562193919.214|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Selected for cluster connection: bootstrap servers added (broker has 0 connection attempt(s))
%7|1562193919.214|INIT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.0.1 (0x10001ff) rdkafka#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd, GCC GXX PKGCONFIG OSXLD LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS ZSTD HDRHISTOGRAM SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM CRC32C_HW, debug 0x46)
%7|1562193919.214|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Enter main broker thread
%7|1562193919.214|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Received CONNECT op
%7|1562193919.214|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1562193919.214|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
%7|1562193919.214|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
%7|1562193919.214|TOPIC|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: New local topic: mytopic
%7|1562193919.214|TOPPARNEW|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: NEW mytopic [-1] 0x7fdc0b7988e0 (at rd_kafka_topic_new0:393)
%7|1562193919.216|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connecting to ipv6#[::1]:9092 (plaintext) with socket 10
%7|1562193919.216|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connected to ipv6#[::1]:9092
%7|1562193919.216|CONNECTED|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connected (#1)
%7|1562193919.216|FEATURE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features +ApiVersion to ApiVersion
%7|1562193919.216|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> APIVERSION_QUERY
%7|1562193919.220|FEATURE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features to MsgVer1,ApiVersion,BrokerBalancedConsumer,ThrottleTime,Sasl,SaslHandshake,BrokerGroupCoordinator,LZ4,OffsetTime,MsgVer2,IdempotentProducer,ZSTD
%7|1562193919.220|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state APIVERSION_QUERY -> UP
%7|1562193919.221|BROKER|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: Added new broker with NodeId 1001
%7|1562193919.221|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Topic mytopic changed state unknown -> exists
%7|1562193919.221|PARTCNT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Topic mytopic partition count changed from 0 to 1
%7|1562193919.221|TOPPARNEW|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: NEW mytopic [0] 0x7fdc0b4d8280 (at rd_kafka_topic_partition_cnt_update:620)
%7|1562193919.221|METADATA|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]:   Topic mytopic partition 0 Leader 1001
%7|1562193919.221|BRKDELGT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: mytopic [0]: delegate to broker 455b444cbea7:9092/1001 (rktp 0x7fdc0b4d8280, term 0, ref 2, remove 0)
%7|1562193919.221|BRKDELGT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: mytopic [0]: broker 455b444cbea7:9092/1001 is now leader for partition with 0 messages (0 bytes) queued
%7|1562193919.221|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: Enter main broker thread
%7|1562193919.221|BRKMIGR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Migrating topic mytopic [0] 0x7fdc0b4d8280 from (none) to 455b444cbea7:9092/1001 (sending PARTITION_JOIN to 455b444cbea7:9092/1001)
%7|1562193919.221|PARTCNT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Partitioning 1 unassigned messages in topic mytopic to 1 partitions
%7|1562193919.221|TOPBRK|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: Topic mytopic [0]: joining broker (rktp 0x7fdc0b4d8280, 0 message(s) queued)
%7|1562193919.221|FETCHADD|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: Added mytopic [0] to active list (1 entries, opv 0, 0 messages queued)
%7|1562193919.221|UAS|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: 1/1 messages were partitioned in topic mytopic
%7|1562193919.221|TOPPAR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: mytopic [0] 1 message(s) queued but broker not up
%7|1562193919.221|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1562193919.221|METADATA|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: 1/1 requested topic(s) seen in metadata
%7|1562193919.221|CLUSTERID|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: ClusterId update "" -> "aOByDyDMTpuVFWCzenRfVw"
%7|1562193919.221|CONTROLLERID|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: ControllerId update -1 -> 1001
%7|1562193919.221|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
%7|1562193919.221|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
%7|1562193919.222|BROKERFAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: failed: err: Local: Host resolution failure: (errno: Bad address)
%7|1562193919.222|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: Broker changed state CONNECT -> DOWN
%7|1562193919.223|TOPPAR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: mytopic [0] 1 message(s) queued but broker not up
%7|1562193920.217|QRYLEADER|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Topic mytopic [0]: leader is down: re-query
%7|1562193920.219|METADATA|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]:   Topic mytopic partition 0 Leader 1001
%7|1562193920.219|METADATA|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: 1/1 requested topic(s) seen in metadata
%7|1562193920.223|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: Broker changed state DOWN -> INIT
%7|1562193920.223|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1562193920.223|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
%7|1562193920.223|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
%7|1562193920.224|BROKERFAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:455b444cbea7:9092/1001]: 455b444cbea7:9092/1001: failed: err: Local: Host resolution failure: (errno: Bad address)
```

**UPDATE**

After modifying the docker compose with kafka listeners the log now reads as follows:

```
%7|1562359630.985|BROKER|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Added new broker with NodeId -1
%7|1562359630.985|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Enter main broker thread
%7|1562359630.985|BRKMAIN|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Enter main broker thread
%7|1562359630.985|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Selected for cluster connection: bootstrap servers added (broker has 0 connection attempt(s))
%7|1562359630.985|INIT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v1.0.1 (0x10001ff) rdkafka#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd, GCC GXX PKGCONFIG OSXLD LIBDL PLUGINS ZLIB SSL SASL_CYRUS ZSTD HDRHISTOGRAM SNAPPY SOCKEM SASL_SCRAM CRC32C_HW, debug 0x46)
%7|1562359630.985|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Received CONNECT op
%7|1562359630.985|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1562359630.985|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
%7|1562359630.985|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
%7|1562359630.985|TOPIC|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: New local topic: anothertopic
%7|1562359630.985|TOPPARNEW|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: NEW anothertopic [-1] 0x7f9fe2e8c350 (at rd_kafka_topic_new0:393)
produce called
calling flush
%7|1562359630.987|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connecting to ipv6#[::1]:9092 (plaintext) with socket 10
%7|1562359630.987|CONNECT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connected to ipv6#[::1]:9092
%7|1562359630.987|CONNECTED|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connected (#1)
%7|1562359630.987|FEATURE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features +ApiVersion to ApiVersion
%7|1562359630.987|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> APIVERSION_QUERY
%7|1562359630.994|FEATURE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features to MsgVer1,ApiVersion,BrokerBalancedConsumer,ThrottleTime,Sasl,SaslHandshake,BrokerGroupCoordinator,LZ4,OffsetTime,MsgVer2,IdempotentProducer,ZSTD
%7|1562359630.994|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state APIVERSION_QUERY -> UP
%7|1562359630.999|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Topic anothertopic changed state unknown -> exists
%7|1562359630.999|PARTCNT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Topic anothertopic partition count changed from 0 to 1
%7|1562359630.999|TOPPARNEW|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: NEW anothertopic [0] 0x7f9fe2e8d420 (at rd_kafka_topic_partition_cnt_update:620)
%7|1562359630.999|METADATA|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]:   Topic anothertopic partition 0 Leader 1001
%7|1562359630.999|BRKDELGT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: anothertopic [0]: delegate to broker (none) (rktp 0x7f9fe2e8d420, term 0, ref 2, remove 0)
%7|1562359630.999|BRKDELGT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: anothertopic [0]: broker :0/internal is now leader for partition with 0 messages (0 bytes) queued
%7|1562359630.999|BRKMIGR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Migrating topic anothertopic [0] 0x7f9fe2e8d420 from (none) to :0/internal (sending PARTITION_JOIN to :0/internal)
%7|1562359630.999|PARTCNT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Partitioning 1 unassigned messages in topic anothertopic to 1 partitions
%7|1562359630.999|TOPBRK|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Topic anothertopic [0]: joining broker (rktp 0x7f9fe2e8d420, 0 message(s) queued)
%7|1562359630.999|FETCHADD|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Added anothertopic [0] to active list (1 entries, opv 0, 0 messages queued)
%7|1562359630.999|UAS|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: 1/1 messages were partitioned in topic anothertopic
%7|1562359630.999|UPDATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: NodeId changed from -1 to 1001
%7|1562359630.999|UPDATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Name changed from localhost:9092/bootstrap to localhost:9092/1001
%7|1562359630.999|METADATA|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: localhost:9092/1001: 1/1 requested topic(s) seen in metadata
%7|1562359630.999|TOPICUPD|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: Topic anothertopic [0] migrated from broker -1 to 1001
%7|1562359630.999|BRKDELGT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: anothertopic [0]: delegate to broker localhost:9092/1001 (rktp 0x7f9fe2e8d420, term 0, ref 2, remove 0)
%7|1562359630.999|BRKDELGT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: anothertopic [0]: broker :0/internal no longer leader
%7|1562359630.999|BRKDELGT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: anothertopic [0]: broker localhost:9092/1001 is now leader for partition with 1 messages (7 bytes) queued
%7|1562359630.999|BRKMIGR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: Migrating topic anothertopic [0] 0x7f9fe2e8d420 from :0/internal to localhost:9092/1001 (sending PARTITION_LEAVE to :0/internal)
%7|1562359630.999|LEADER|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Mapped 1 partition(s) to broker
%7|1562359630.999|TOPBRK|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Topic anothertopic [0]: leaving broker (0 messages in xmitq, next leader localhost:9092/1001, rktp 0x7f9fe2e8d420)
%7|1562359630.999|FETCHADD|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Removed anothertopic [0] from active list (0 entries, opv 0)
%7|1562359630.999|CLUSTERID|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: localhost:9092/1001: ClusterId update "" -> "81Cu9QJLRwerPnUGz-DzjA"
%7|1562359630.999|CONTROLLERID|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: localhost:9092/1001: ControllerId update -1 -> 1001
%7|1562359630.999|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Broker changed state UP -> UPDATE
%7|1562359630.999|TOPBRK|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Topic anothertopic [0]: joining broker (rktp 0x7f9fe2e8d420, 1 message(s) queued)
%7|1562359630.999|FETCHADD|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Added anothertopic [0] to active list (1 entries, opv 0, 1 messages queued)
%7|1562359630.999|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Broker changed state UPDATE -> UP
%7|1562359630.999|PRODUCE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: anothertopic [0]: Produce MessageSet with 1 message(s) (75 bytes, ApiVersion 7, MsgVersion 2, MsgId 0, BaseSeq -1, PID{Invalid})
Message delivered to anothertopic [0]
flush called
%7|1562359631.003|MSGSET|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: anothertopic [0]: MessageSet with 1 message(s) (MsgId 0, BaseSeq -1) delivered
%7|1562359631.056|DESTROY|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Terminating instance (destroy flags none (0x0))
%7|1562359631.056|DESTROY|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Destroy internal
%7|1562359631.056|DESTROY|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Removing all topics
%7|1562359631.056|PARTCNT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Topic anothertopic partition count changed from 1 to 0
%7|1562359631.056|REMOVE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: anothertopic [0] no longer reported in metadata
%7|1562359631.056|BRKMIGR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: anothertopic [0] 0x7f9fe2e8d420 sending final LEAVE for removal by localhost:9092/1001
%7|1562359631.056|TOPPARREMOVE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Removing toppar anothertopic [-1] 0x7f9fe2e8c350
%7|1562359631.056|DESTROY|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: anothertopic [-1]: 0x7f9fe2e8c350 DESTROY_FINAL
%7|1562359631.056|DESTROY|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Sending TERMINATE to localhost:9092/1001
%7|1562359631.056|TERM|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Received TERMINATE op in state INIT: 1 refcnts, 0 toppar(s), 0 active toppar(s), 0 outbufs, 0 waitresps, 0 retrybufs
%7|1562359631.056|BROKERFAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: failed: err: Local: Broker handle destroyed: (errno: Undefined error: 0)
%7|1562359631.056|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Client is terminating (after 71ms in state INIT)
%7|1562359631.056|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Broker changed state INIT -> DOWN
%7|1562359631.056|TOPBRK|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Topic anothertopic [0]: leaving broker (0 messages in xmitq, next leader (none), rktp 0x7f9fe2e8d420)
%7|1562359631.056|FETCHADD|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Removed anothertopic [0] from active list (0 entries, opv 0)
%7|1562359631.056|TOPBRK|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Topic anothertopic [0]: no next leader, failing 0 message(s) in partition queue
%7|1562359631.056|TERMINATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Handle is terminating in state DOWN: 1 refcnts (0x7f9fe24fb728), 0 toppar(s), 0 active toppar(s), 0 outbufs, 0 waitresps, 0 retrybufs: failed 0 request(s) in retry+outbuf
%7|1562359631.056|BROKERFAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: failed: err: Local: Broker handle destroyed: (errno: Undefined error: 0)
%7|1562359631.056|TOPPARREMOVE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: Removing toppar anothertopic [0] 0x7f9fe2e8d420
%7|1562359631.056|DESTROY|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: anothertopic [0]: 0x7f9fe2e8d420 DESTROY_FINAL
%7|1562359631.056|TERM|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Received TERMINATE op in state UP: 1 refcnts, 0 toppar(s), 0 active toppar(s), 0 outbufs, 0 waitresps, 0 retrybufs
%7|1562359631.056|BROKERFAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: failed: err: Local: Broker handle destroyed: (errno: Resource temporarily unavailable)
%7|1562359631.056|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Client is terminating (after 57ms in state UP)
%7|1562359631.056|STATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Broker changed state UP -> DOWN
%7|1562359631.056|TERMINATE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: Handle is terminating in state DOWN: 1 refcnts (0x7f9fe24da128), 0 toppar(s), 0 active toppar(s), 0 outbufs, 0 waitresps, 0 retrybufs: failed 0 request(s) in retry+outbuf
%7|1562359631.056|BROKERFAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/1001: failed: err: Local: Broker handle destroyed: (errno: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your topic creation request gets forwarded down into Zookeeper, and is not returned back to the producer API.

You need to setup the Docker image differently to be able to produce and consume outside of a (Python) container

For bitnami, I was able to get these working

```
ports:
    - 9092:9092
    - 29092:29092
environment:
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:9092
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

And add your existing environment variables

Comment: After making these changes the log claims the message is delivered. However, the message does not show up in the topic when I inspect it and I still get some errors in the log. Would you mind checking the update I have included above?

Comment: Inspecting the topic how? By default, you are consuming from only the latest offset, so you wouldn't see existing data

Comment: I'm using kafdrop to look at the topic, and then the messages in that topic. I do see the topic, but it appears to have no messages in it. https://github.com/HomeAdvisor/Kafdrop

Comment: kafdrop was not working, switched to using kadeck and was able to see the messages.

Comment: Sounds like a tool misconfiguration, not necessarily a problem with Kafka or your client